# Python how can I import a variable from another file if it's in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 Python files: `file1.py` and `file2.py`. I want to import a variable from `file1.py` inside the `file2.py` but the variable is in a function. Here are the codes:

`file1.py`

```py
class Ezber():
    def ask():
        value = "test string"
```

`file2.py`

```py
from file1.py import *
print(value)
```

Is there any possibility of doing this?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: You dont have the variable 'value' in just another function, but a class method.. why not define the variable as a member of the class Ezber itself??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot access that information. The biggest reason is that `ask()` hasn't even been executed at the time of import. Therefor, the `value` variable hasn't been created.

More generally, however, unless you're writing something like a debugger or other diagnostic tool, you should not be trying to inspect the local variables of another block of code. If the `ask()` function needs to supply data to another module, it should do so through a return value or other documented way of sending information.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do what you're asking for, and it has nothing to do with the fact that your code resides in two different files. You would still have the same issue if you were trying to access a function's local variables inside the same file the function is declared.

The reason why you can't do this is that `value` is a local variable of function `ask`. This means that this variable will be pushed onto the stack whenever the function `ask` is called, and then removed once the execution of `ask` is over. So, it doesn't exist outside the scope of function `ask`'s execution. You can understand why this happens by considering the scenario below:

```
def f(a):
   value = a + 2
```

Now, the value of variable `value` is not clear except for when the function f has been called. (f(2) would mean that value == 4, but f(3) would mean that value == 5).

But, if you have a variable whose value doesn't depend on any other arguments to the function, you can either declare it global (wouldn't recommend it), or make it a static variable like below:

```
class Ezber():
    def ask():
        # do something
        pass

Ezber.ask.value = "test string"

print(Ezber.ask.value)
```

Or, if you want the initialization to happen inside the function, you can do:

```
class Ezber():
    def ask():
        # do something
        Ezber.ask.value = "test string"

ezber = Ezber()
ezber.ask()

print(Ezber.ask.value)
```

But as you can see, you'll need to at least call `ask` once before you can access `value`. (since `value` is initialized only when `ask` is executed).

Answer (score 0):

QUESTION SOLVED.
I've done it by this way:

```py
class Ezber:
    def ask(self):
        value = "test"
        return value
```

```py
from file1 import *
print(Ezber().ask())
```